# Port configuration and automatic port change on Wakanda

Tags: wakanda

When I run a solution on Wakanda there is a port by default, for example 8102, but when I reload it the port changes to 8104. I would have liked to know where the port configuration is and this operation is done? In which file, or option? Because I look for it, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion it's because your previous solution didn't shutdown correctly. You can check your solution settings, ports usually start from 8100.

Comment: Wakanda has three types of default port: project port (8080), Angular 1 application port (8000) and Angular 4 application port (4200). The defaults all can be edited. As Jonathan pointed out, if previous application/project is not closed properly, Wakanda will use next available port to avoid port conflict. This is common in development and less likely to happen in production as the application is less likely to be launched multiple times when deployed. Can you specify your use case?

Comment: I'm trying to put Wakanda server on a remote server, but I can not access port 8080. I have this following message: "The Administration Web Server listens for connections on port 8080 on all IP addresses. Note that unsecured remote connections will be refused". So I can't access  to the admin view like on local, where I can access to 8080/admin.

Comment: Is it possible to access the application via port 8080 instead of port 8101? Where can I change that, in which file? Can I prevent the port from incrementing?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I have confirmed that when accessed remotely (from another computer), the admin dashboard is only available via HTTPS at port 4433. :8080/admin is available on localhost only.

In order for it to work, the CORS settings need to be enabled for port 4433 as well:
**HostIPAddress:4433  POST / GET / PUT / DELETE**

Note: From your earlier comment it seems you have admin dashboard working on port 4433. FYI the server has an updated admin certificate, which will come out in next release. In case you have any problem with it, please wait and test with next release.

-------------------------Original Post-----------------------------------------

The admin port is set to 8080 by default. If you would like to change the default value of admin port (typically for deployment), it can be changed using Command Line/ Terminal option "--admin-port=[number]", for example:

```
"C:\Wakanda\Wakanda Server.exe" "C:\solutions\invoices.waSolution" "--adminport=8090"
```

Will change solution invoices's admin port to 8090.

You can find more options in the [documentation](https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main-admin).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I had already try to do this and I have the same error with the new port. I can "access" to the solution via https and 4433 for the port, but that tell me I don't have any project. I want to know how I can access to the solution, even with the default port.

Comment: I want to access to the solution via http too.

Comment: Port 4433 via https is supposed to take you to admin page where you can view projects and manage them like start/stop. The error where you do no have any project might be a separate issue. The projects in a solution by default requires port 8081 and above. Are you sure all the ports including the custom admin port and project ports are all available?  You can find out whether a project is started in the server logs.

Comment: I have my project in the wakanda-server Ressources folder. I run it as follows: ./wakanda-server ../Ressources/TestApp/app.waSolution, In this way I can see my project via :8080/admin. On the other hands when I am on the port :8080 this redirects me to :8080/index.html, but it is a blank page. I can't access my project. I would like to publish my project and be able to access it from anywhere. What is the process to follow ? Are there any options to modify in the project ?

Comment: with ":8081" I have "503 - Service Unavailable"

Comment: with ":8080/rest/$info/HTTPConnections" I have "{"HTTPConnections":[]}"